# How to setup a node JS app as a subdirectory of a regular website without modifying DNS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, hosting, centos7

I'm working on a project with low resources and many restrictions I need to deploy an app as a subdirectory for an existing website, there are already some configured, and I have to maintain them while deploying my website.

With this kind of structure:

`https://example.com` - `https://example.com/example`

For the server, we are using CentOS 7, and it is configured with Apache.

There is already configured a virtualhost like this `/etc/httpd/conf.d`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        #Redirect / https://example.com/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file is also configured

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js, so I tried this script:

```js
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I thought I could open other port, but I'm not sure how that could affect the SSL certificate. I have some issues modifying DNS, so my team preferred avoid to modificate it

In my first attempt, I was using Python, but I encountered too many issues with the server. I tried opening ports and was researching Name-Based Hosting and Virtual Hosting.

#################### UPDATE ####################

I'm trying to configure a reverse proxy like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        #Redirect / https://example.com/

        <Location /example>
              ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
              ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
        </Location>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `example.com/example` is a subdirectory.   A subdomain is `subdir.example.com/`  What do you actually want?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I want a subdirectory, I misunderstood the concept

Comment: It sounds like you want to run your application on a different port and the use a reverse proxy in that apache subdirectory.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I want to redirect requests from that subdirectory to my node app. My node app is already in that directory, but I need to run it as far as I know. I just tried this, but still not working. It still shows Index of /example with files and directories 
```
<Location /example>
   ProxyPass /example http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse /example http://localhost:3000/
 </Location>
```

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making those config changes?  Have you enabled `mod_proxy`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I already restarted Apache, and I searched for enable mod_proxy and It looked already enabled. I also changed the address only in .conf file to see if it works like /exampledev and, while node was running, I received 404

Comment: Where is the configuration for everything that was already existing?  I would expect to see it in the same `<VirtualHost>` section.

Comment: I didn't configure it. As I know it is set ServerName and SSL certificate in one <Virtualhost *:80> I updated my question to add a very similar .conf file as mine with the proxy configuration